# Can you pass no Values to a Java Parameter Array

Tags: java, arrays, java-5

Most people should know of the `Object... objs` way of having an array as a parameter. Essentially it's just `Object[] objs`. However I found something, where you can't match the functionality. (Or I just don't know how)

```
//  How does one go about calling this method?
void test(String s, String... strings, String s2) {}
```

And how would you accomplish this with the `...` syntax?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    foo(new String[] {}); //  foo(new String[0]);
}

static void foo(String[] s) {}
```

Comment: You can't even compile such a method, let alone call it.

Comment: What specific problem are you trying to solve? Or are you _only_ asking about syntax?

Comment: @Joakim Danielson
No, you obviously can still do this, but it got introduced in 1.5

Comment: Why do you think "you can do this"? https://ideone.com/KRjmCq `Main.java:10: error: varargs parameter must be the last parameter
 static void junk(Object a, Object ... b, Object c){`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
//  How does one go about calling this method?
void test(String s, String s2, String... strings) {}
```

but this is not a valid

```
//  How does one go about calling this method?
void test(String s, String... strings, String s2) {}
```

an excerpt from https://www.baeldung.com/java-varargs

> varargs are straightforward to use. But there're a few rules we have to keep in mind:
>
> - Each method can only have one varargs parameter
> - The varargs argument must be the last parameter